# how to change the Browser based error message in devexpress

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I am having aspxgridview inside the gridview i have GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn

is there that column allow only jpg,png,jpeg files.

That column allows max file size is 4mb

now my question is if upload other (jpg,png,jpeg) i should get error like this "Please Select different files format.Choose only". jpg,png,jpeg.

if i upload more or less file size means i should get error like this"Please upload file size between 4kb to 4mb!"

Comment: Are you using the ASPxFileUpload control for the actual image upload?

Comment: i am using aspxgridview in side that GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn using this.  How to change the default error message in that.

Comment: You can set the BinaryImageValidationSettings property for a GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn. See: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebBinaryImageValidationSettingsMembersTopicAll